# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After the execution of code following exception occurred at the end of code, I have do a lot of changes in the code but nothing change at all.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   RocketController.Start () (at Assets/Script/RocketController.cs:10)

What is the cause of this exception?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RocketController : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
Rigidbody2D rd;
void Start () {

    rd.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if(Input.GetKey("right"))
    {
        rd.velocity = new Vector2(1,0);
    }
    else if(Input.GetKey("left"))
    {
        rd.velocity = new Vector2(-1,0);
    }
    else
    {
        rd.velocity = new Vector2(0,0);
    }


  }//close update
}
```

Comment: Is `rd` ever instantiated? It seems to be always null in your code, so doing `rd.anything` will throw that exception.

Comment: The irony of the comment `// Use this for initialization` right above the problem. :)

Comment: you have mistaken how GetComponent works you need to call that from the controller and assign it to the rd field, not call it from the null rd field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Here is working code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class RocketController : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
Rigidbody2D rd;
void Start () {

    rd = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if(rd == null)
        return;
    if(Input.GetKey("right"))
    {
        rd.velocity = new Vector2(1,0);
    }
    else if(Input.GetKey("left"))
    {
        rd.velocity = new Vector2(-1,0);
    }
    else
    {
        rd.velocity = new Vector2(0,0);
    }


  }//close update
}
```

Comment: Include above line before class definition i got these error: Attribute 'RequireComponent' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class' declarations.

Comment: @user3662189 I guess you were not writing it at correct place, I have updated my answer. check it

Comment: This code is not working i simply just copy and paste but its not working at all - here is the repeat error : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: on which line is it now?

Comment: in the end of code after else

Comment: just add a null check in update like i did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122689/discussion-between-umair-m-and-user3662189).

Comment: i got my answer simply add the component of rigid body in unity and its all work fine with my old code thanks buddy for your time and valuable answer

Comment: `[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]` actually adds the component automatically if you dont attach it manually. This should have worked :)

Comment: @UmairM if the annotation was added after the script was attached to a object I don't think it will automatically add the component.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `rd` is never instantiated so it is null. You need to instantiate it before you can use it.

A `NullReferenceException` means that, the thing you are trying to work with is null.

The way to instantiate a rigid body in Unity is to it as follow: `rd = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();`
[More info](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/931497/begginner-get-rigidbody-component-in-script-c.html)

Comment: this is exactly how initialization work in Unity. either you assign component from inspector. or you use `GetComponent`. OP is just using `GetComponent` in wrong manner.

Comment: i have change it but it remains same as before MissingComponentException: There is no 'Rigidbody2D' attached to the "rocket" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Rigidbody2D to the game object "rocket".

Comment: @user3662189 that means the object that the script is attached to has no `Rigidbody2D`, so you need to add one to the object or not use `Rigidbody2D`

Comment: @user3662189 follow [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39334574/4366237).